# Facebook authentication using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: facebook, selenium, webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver, I want to handle Facebook authentication and get Access Token with the HtmlUnitDriver, how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

a lot of this are functions whose purposes you'll have to infer, but this is a test I wrote of the oauth flow itself:

```
$this->loginAsTestUser();

$oauth_uri = $this->fbURI()
  ->setPath('/dialog/oauth')
  ->addQueryData('client_id', self::RELL_APP_ID)
  ->addQueryData('redirect_uri', self::RELL_URL);
$this->open($oauth_uri);
$this->platform->tosApp();

$code = $this->getURI()->getQueryData('code');
$this->assertNotEmpty($code, 'No code returned in redirect url');

$token_uri = $this->fbURI('graph')
  ->setSecure(true)
  ->setPath('/oauth/access_token')
  ->addQueryData('client_id', self::RELL_APP_ID)
  ->addQueryData('client_secret', self::RELL_SECRET)
  ->addQueryData('code', $code)
  ->addQueryData('redirect_uri', self::RELL_URL);
$this->open($token_uri);
$this->assertRegExp(
  '/access_token=.+/', $this->source(),
  'No access token returned in source');
```

Comment: I believe this is at the REST API level using HTTP requests, bypassing Selenium to perform the UI login?